# Asc/Desc sort order as parameter in native query in Spring boot and Hibernate application with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I have Spring boot, Hibernate, and SQL Server.

We use Native queries and they are very big, so I can't rewrite them in JPQL or HQL.
I need a way to make the sort order dynamic, I have a query similar to this:

```
select * from (select 1 as id, 'Max' as name
union 
select 2 as id, 'Mike' as name) as a
order by a.id :sortOrder
```

:sortOrder hibernate changes to `?` so I'm getting `order by a.id ?`
:sortOrder should be `asc` or `desc`, but I'm getting an error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P1'

How can I make sort order dynamic?

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing a presentation concern? i.e.: wouldn't the data grid in your GUI have sort ordering on its column headers or some other UI gadget?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning If the application is using pagination, sorting is not just a presentation concern. Sorting by a given column in the UI vs in the database/back-end could give different results.

Comment: @PeterBergman and yet there are no `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` keywords in the `ORDER BY` clause so pagination doesn't apply. Ref: [Specifying integer constants for OFFSET and FETCH values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql#a-specifying-integer-constants-for-offset-and-fetch-values)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible for native query, you can use JPA anyway but if you really wanna use native query?
Use different methoads one for ASC and one for DESC and hardcode the sortOrder